# Ensuring that a curve $\gamma : [0,1] \to M$ lies on an integral manifold of a distribution $E \subset TM$

Tags: differential-geometry, tangent-bundle, foliations

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $E \subset TM$ a smooth distribution of codimension $k$, and $\gamma : [0,1] \to M$ a smooth curve whose tangent vector is in $\gamma^\star E$, and whose individual points are contained in integral manifolds of $E$. Can we deduce that $\gamma$ is entirely contained in a *single* connected integral manifold of $E$?

If $E$ is integrable, then the answer is “yes”, and I can prove it as follows. For each $t \in [0,1]$, take a distinguished chart in which $E$ is defined by $dx^1 = \dots = dx^k = 0$. Then $\gamma$ is locally contained in a single plaque of this chart. Then we have an *open* cover of $\gamma$ by plaques. Take a finite subcover, and their union is a connected integral manifold of $E$ containing $\gamma$.

But what if $E$ is not integrable?

**EDIT:** Rewrote whole question.

---

Never mind, I am no longer in a hurry for an answer. I just realized that I can prove the global Frobenius theorem (every involutive distribution gives rise to a foliation) using only connectedness of the integral manifolds, not path-connectedness.

Comment: If $D$ isn’t integrable, what do you mean by an integral manifold $L$?

Comment: @TedShifrin It seems the meaning is that the integral manifolds of $E$ does not cover $M$, even though $E$ has at least one integral manifold. Although it seems to me the question doesn't really have much to do with $E$.

Comment: Are your integral manifolds still maximal?

Comment: @TedShifrin: My bad, I was away. They need not be maximal, but I can assume I have enough of them to cover the curve.

Comment: That sounds a lot like begging the question to me.

Comment: @pyon Instead it might be better to ask for the curve to be in the manifold locally in time.

Comment: @AlpUzman: Thanks. I rewrote the question. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: I just saw the edit. For manifolds, path-connectedness and connectedness are equivalent. You should be able to prove this immediately.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Thanks. I was trying to untangle the proof of the global Frobenius theorem I found in two differential geometry books. In the end, I realized that path-connectedness was a distraction (smooth and regular path-connectedness even more so!) for my purposes, and I only needed to use connectedness.